# What kinda math is this? Got it from my Grade 12 data Management

Tags: probability

A rummage bin has one copy of each 66 Garfield books. If you reach in and pick out three Garfield books without looking, what is the probability they are three consecutive books in the series?

I’m confused on this question if you could help that would be great!:)

Also what tag should this actually be under?

Answer (score 2):

HINT How many different ways are there to get 3 books out of 66?  And how many sequences are there of three consecutive books? Divide the latter by the former, and you have your probability.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I means that my auto-correct went on the fritz :)